# Deploy image built with buildah to Azure container instance from Azure container registry

Tags: azure, containers, podman, buildah

So I have built an image using Buildah and have pushed it up to the ACR (azure container registry) but any method I try, AZ cli, portal, terraform, the deployment to ACI (azure container instance) fails after 30 minutes due to a timeout. The ACI is created successfully, the image can be pushed and pulled successfully from the ACR, and the image runs locally using podman. The ACI hangs trying to create the container from the image.

### Error displayed

```
Deployment to resource group '<my-resource-group>' failed.
Additional details from the underlying API that might be helpful: At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details
```

### Raw Error

```
 {
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "message": "Subscription deployment didn't reach a successful provisioning state after '00:30:00'."
    }
  ]
}
```

Any suggestions as to what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

### The resolution

---

Even though the documentation states that ACR and ACI can utilize OCI images, it would seem that ACI still requires images to use the docker format. When using buildah to create an image you need to use the --format  docker flag  -> `buildah bud --format docker` in order for the image to pull from ACR and deploy into an ACI.